# How to fill values in condition in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables like following

I'd like to fill `col2`in`9999/12/31` by referring to `col1==A`

```
col1   col2
A     2011/1/1
B     2013/4/1
C     2000/1/1
A     2010/1/1
```

Therefore my desired result is following

Are there any way to achieve this?

```
col1   col2
A     9999/12/31
B     2013/4/1
C     2000/1/1
A     9999/12/31
```

If someone has opinion,please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Is col2 a date?

Comment: Are these two different tables?

Comment: Do you want to modify the data or just produce a result set?

Answer (score 1):

If you have one table and that's all that needs updating then:

```sql
UPDATE [table] SET col2 = '31-DEC-9999' WHERE col1 = 'A';
```

If they're two different tables you could just run `CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM table1` and then just run that `UPDATE` above ^. Sure it's an extra step but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add case statement to your query:

```
SELECT COL1, CASE WHEN COL1 = 'A' THEN '9999/12/31' ELSE COL2 END AS COL2 FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: The OP specified that they wanted to "fill", so an UPDATE is probably a more appropriate answer than a SELECT.